# How to execute a query with SQL Alchemy and store the result into a variable type int

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm looking to execute a query and convert that result into an integer variable in Python, but I'm not exactly sure how to accomplish that.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

conn = engine_azure.connect()

# just the name of my table
blob_name = blob_name.split('_')[0]

# Tried with and without TOP 1 specified
sql_query = text("SELECT TOP 1 MAX(StagingID) FROM ["+blob_name+"]")

result = conn.execute(sql_query)

# thought this might work but no luck
result_int = result.fetchone()
```

I understand that this is also not the best practice way of executing that query, so I'm all ears on how to correct that as well.

Essentially I'm just looking for a way to get the max StagingID and store that into a variable of type int in Python. Instead of the cursor object I'm getting now.